# Django request not recognized

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pylance

I am currently learning Django with video tutorials and I came across a problem I can't get rid of.
I am in the views file of one of my apps and when I try to use "request" it tells me '"request" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable'

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def home_view(*args, **kwargs):

    return render(request, "home.html", {})

def contact_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>contact page</h1>")
```

[view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQJPO.png)

I tried importing HttpRequests and modifying the code to fit but it then tells me that it doesn't have a META attribute when I run the server
[runserver error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBYEM.png)

I'd like to use "request" and not import a new library for it as it should come with django, the guy in the tutorial I watch just types in request and it works.I couldn't find anything in the Django docs and it seems like using request shouldn't even be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` is the first parameter of a view function, you thus need to specify this explicitly:

```
#                ↓ request parameter
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Comment: thanks, I'll print myself a python/django cheat sheet, can't understand how I didn't see that it seems very obvious now